# Space between FlatButton in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C1Te.jpg)Hello I am making an application where i need to maximize and minimise the screen.But i want to reduce space between 'A+'(i.e. maximising the screen) and 'A-'(i.e. minimising).I am attaching an image for better understanding.Thank you.

> Here is the code:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF125688),
        actions: <Widget>[
           FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('A+',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
                ),)),

          FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('A-',style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
            ),),

          )

        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        titleSpacing: 10,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF125688),
        actions: <Widget>[
           SizedBox(
             width: 30,
             child: FlatButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('A+',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
                ),))),

          SizedBox(
             width: 30,
             child:FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('A-',style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white
            ),),

          ))

        ],
      ))
```

Comment: It worked thank you.How can i maximize the content when i tap on A+.In  android i did using set.textsize.

Comment: @Chinmay use a variable for the fontsize of your content, then when tapping on A+, change your variable value with the SetState function.

Answer (score 0):

Image of the Flatbutton:

[image]

```
Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
        ),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: FlatButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          onPressed: () {
            // Write the function
          },
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Add a Note"),
              Icon(
                Icons.note_add,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).